# Universally measurable but not analytically measurable set

Tags: measure-theory, descriptive-set-theory

is there a concrete example (or even a non-concrete example) of a universally measurable set which is not analytically measurable (i.e., not in the sigma-algebra generated by the analytic sets)?

Comment: Semi-concrete: The smallest $\sigma$-algebra containing the analytic sets with the property that the resulting space of measurable functions is closed under composition is larger than the $\sigma$-algebra generated by analytic sets and consists of universally measurable sets. So for some Borel set, the preimage under the composition of two analytic functions is not analytically measurable. Details are in Appendix B of "Stochastic Optimal Control: The Discrete-Time Case" by Bertsekas and Shreve.

Comment: Maybe there is something along the lines: there are $2^{\mathfrak c}$ universally measurable sets on $\mathbb R$, but only $\mathfrak c = 2^{\aleph_0}$ analytically measurable sets.

Comment: A much larger collection than $\sigma(\Sigma_1^1),$ but all still universally measurable, are the $C$-sets (the collection of sets closed under $\sigma$-algebra operations and the Souslin $A$-operation). Maybe one of these papers will lead to something qualifying as "concrete": [*Measure and category approximations for* $C$-*sets*](https://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1983-278-02/S0002-9947-1983-0701507-4/) by Srivatsa; [*Probability measures and the* $C$-*sets of Selivanovskij*](https://msp.org/pjm/1978/79-1/p17.xhtml) by Shreve (1978); **(continued)**

Comment: [*From preference to utility: a problem of descriptive set theory*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22from+preference+to+utility%22+%22Burgess%22) by Burgess (1985).

Comment: Thanks to all those who responded, I'll check the reference.
Gerald: I believe, it is consist with ZFC that there are only a continuum of universally measurable sets, although I don't recall a reference on-hand.