# Which is the smallest $\sigma$-algebra that contains all analytic sets?

Tags: measure-theory, descriptive-set-theory

Let $X$ be a polish space. Is the smallest $\sigma$-Algebra containing all analytic sets of $X$ (i.e. all subsets $A \subset X$ which are the continuous image of a polish space) the $\sigma$-algebra of the universally measurable sets (intersection of all completions w.r.t. a finite measure)?

Comment: [Possible duplicate question](https://mathoverflow.net/q/396694/17064) (the linked question doesn't have an answer, but it has references in the comments — of which I'm not sure whether they constitute an answer).

Comment: I think there can be (and there are, unless $X$ is countable) universally measurable sets beyond that $\sigma$-algebra. The reason is that measurability w.r.t. a nice measure is preserved by Suslin's Operation A. So you can apply operation A to sets from your $\sigma$-algebra, then close again under countable union and complement, then apply A again, etc., (finally obtaining what are classically  called the C-sets) all while staying within the universally measurable sets.  (The main reason this is only a comment is that I' m not sure exactly what I meant by "nice measure".)

Comment: Oops. The comments on the question linked by @Gro-Tsen include essentially everything in my previous comment here.

Comment: I'm not adding anything new compared to the previous comments, but if you want a precise reference Exercise 29.17 of *Classical Descriptive Set Theory* by Kechris asks to show that $\sigma(\mathbf{\Sigma}^1_1(X))\subsetneq\mathcal A\mathbf{\Pi}^1_1(X)\subsetneq C(X)$, where $X$ is Polish, the first collection of sets is the $\sigma$-algebra generated by the analytic sets, the second is the closure of the coanalytic sets under the Souslin operation and the third is the class of $C$-sets, which are still all universally measurable